# Navigation drawer и profile switcher

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, switch, profile

Хочу реализовать переключение профилей (как в gmail app) используя лишь классы из стандартных библиотек поддержки.

`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

`android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

Есть ли где хорошие статьи, где описана реализация?
Интересуют тонкости, напр. как правильней делать, переключать фрагменты или играться с view.visibility или же скрывать пункты меню NavigationView->app:menu и тд. Весь процесс.

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли вы найдёте статью именно про такую фичу.

Делать это надо как-то так:

1. В БД хранить юзеров и инфу какие пункты в меню для них отображать
2. В SharedPreferences, например, хранить какой именно юзер сейчас активен.
3. При смене юзера у вас должен вызываться метод, отображающий нужные списки/менюшки для конкретного юзера, согласно инфе из объекта юзера.

Также не лишним будет предусмотреть запуск приложения отдельными тасками (стеками активити) для разных юзеров.

Comment: Спасибо, но модель я знаю. Мне реализацию ui надо.

Comment: @Andreyua, cобственно реализация UI из сего и следует - у вас должен быть один интерфейс для всех юзеров и метод замены контента в нём. В них уже можете скрывать показывать вьюхи или загружать новый ресурс меню. Например нужды в переключении к-л фрагментов я тут не вижу.

Comment: Я понимаю что она следует из этого, но мне не нужно "следует", мне нужно "внутренности" реализации ui. Голый код тупо ui, никакой модели, понимаете?

Comment: @Andreyua, ну... Если вы ищите некий стандарт, то, думаю, его нет. Если вам надо пример реализации - то можете посмотреть вот эту либу - там такое, вроде, есть: [materialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). Если там нет, то, думаю, надо ждать что найдётся тут кто-то кто этот код вам напишет. Но это маловероятно. Проще самостоятельно.

Comment: Эту либу я видел. Если ничего не найду лучше, буду из неё реализацию изучать ... В этой либе не используется NavigationView , у него там свой к сожалению, а может и нет :) Посмотрим

Comment: И не мне код напишет, а всем интересующимся может кто то напишет. Например как написали floating button  с menu и без левых либов.